# Nesting v. interaction in LMM

Tags: interaction, mixed-model

I have a continuous response variable, a continuous predictor (P1) and a variable (elevation, P2) that could be treated either as continuous or categorical (I guess?). I also have an ID as the random effect. My aim is to find out about the effect of P1 on the response variable, but only in combination with (or taking into consideration) the respective elevation, as the effects of P1 and P2 could otherwise potentially cancel each other out. 
Now I am confused as to whether I need an interaction term (P1:P2) in my LMM or whether this calls for some sort of nesting?

I hope I gave enough information, thanks for any advice on the matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting is an issue with experimental design.  You don't have that (at least, not from what you've written).

You *might* have interaction between P1 and P2.  That would mean that the effect of P1 on the response variable was different at different levels of P2 and, similarly, that the effect of P2 on the response variable was different at different levels of P1.

Comment: So if I understand correctly it's then not possible to determine the "direction" of the interaction, i.e. consider the effect of P1 as entirely dependant on P2?

Comment: Interactions don't really have a direction.